# How to pass a collection view cell's indexPath to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm following a tutorial for making an Instagram-esque app, and the tutorial goes through how to display all data (image, author, likes, etc) all in one collection view. I'm trying to do it a little bit differently so only the images are displayed in the collection view, then if an image is tapped, the user is taken to a different view controller where the image plus all the other data is displayed.

So in my view controller with the collection view (`FeedViewController`), I have my array of posts declared outside the class (`Post` is the object with all the aforementioned data):

```
var posts = [Post]()
```

Then inside the `FeedViewController` class, my `cellForItemAt indexPath` looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    // creating the cell
    cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)

    photoDetailController.authorNameLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].author
    photoDetailController.likeLabel.text = "\(posts[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
    photoDetailController.photoDetailImageView.downloadImage(from: posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)

    return cell
}
```

And then I also obviously have a function to fetch the data which I can post if necessary, but I think the problem is because `PhotoDetailController` doesn't know the indexPath (although I may be wrong).

When I run the app and try to view the `FeedViewController` I get a crash `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, highlighting `photoDetailController.authorNameLabel` line.

Am I correct in assuming the problem is because the indexPath is available only in the collection view data sources within `FeedViewController`? If so, how can I pass that indexPath to `PhotoDetailController` so my code works correctly?

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: Edited my `didSelectItem` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let photoDetailController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photoDetail") as! PhotoDetailController

    photoDetailController.selectedPost = posts[indexPath.row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(photoDetailController, animated: true)
}
```

and `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell


    cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)


    return cell
}
```

And in `PhotoDetailController`:

`var selectedPost: Post!` inside the class, then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.authorNameLabel.text = selectedPost[indexPath.row].author
    self.likeLabel.text = "\(selectedPost[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
    self.photoDetailImageView.downloadImage(from: selectedPost[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
}
```

But still getting error `use of unresolved identifier "indexPath`

EDIT 2: Storyboard

[image]

Comment: Use didSelectItemAtIndexPath of collection view and perform segue just like we do for table view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this `nil` crash because this `photoDetailController` is not yet loaded so all its outlet are nil also the way currently you are doing is also wrong.

You need to add the controller code in `didSelectItemAt` method and perform the navigation.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let photoDetailController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifier") as! PhotoDetailController  
    photoDetailController.selectedPost = posts[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(photoDetailController, animated: true)
}
```

Now simply create one instance property of type `Post` with name `selectedPost` in `PhotoDetailController` and set all the detail from this `selectedPost` object in `viewDidLoad` of `PhotoDetailController`.

**Edit:** Set your `viewDidLoad` like this in `PhotoDetailController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.authorNameLabel.text = selectedPost.author
    self.likeLabel.text = "\(selectedPost.likes!) Likes"
    self.photoDetailImageView.downloadImage(from: selectedPost.pathToImage)
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `author` in your code? I'm not sure what that line is doing. But anyway, I should be putting `var post: Post!` inside the `PhotoDetailController` class?

Comment: @KingTim What is author here, have your remove code from `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: Yes I removed the code from `cellForItemAt` method. Author is the user who posted the image. I'm talking about the line `photoDetailController.selectedPost = posts[indexPath.row].author` in your answer - should author be there?

Comment: @KingTim It was my typo mistake it should simply `photoDetailController.selectedPost = posts[indexPath.row]` check the edited answer.

Comment: Cool that's what I figured - I edited my question to show what i now have in `FeedViewController`. Is that correct so far? Now in `PhotoDetailController`, so I understand correctly, I'm putting `var selectedPost: Post!` in the class, and then `self.authorNameLabel.text = selectedPost[indexPath.row].author`, etc inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: @KingTim Yes it is perfect run your application and check it is working in  a way you want.

Comment: See my edit, I show what I have in `PhotoDetailController`, but I'm still getting the error `use of unresolved identifier "indexPath` on each of the lines in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @KingTim To set value in `viewDidLoad` check my latest edit,

Comment: Almost! Now I don't get a crash when I go to `FeedViewController`, but tapping on the cells doesn't take me to `PhotoDetailController` - nothing happens. I'm not sure why because the `pushViewController` should do that, right? Do I need to set up any kind of segue in storyboard? Right now `PhotoDetailController` in storyboard is not hooked up to anything (except the `PhotoDetailController` class of course.

Comment: @KingTim Is your `FeedViewController` embed in `NavigationController` if yes check that CollectionView delegate is set or not if not then set, also put the break point in didSelect method and check it is called or not.

Comment: I'm not using a navigation controller, I just added navigation bars in storyboard. And I set a breakpoint on the `didSelect` method and it is indeed getting called (I get a crash when I tap an image)

Comment: @KingTim Is `FeedViewController` is your initial screen means first screen?

Comment: No, The app loads on a login page then you're taken to a tableview of users. That page has a bar button item that takes you to `FeedViewController`

Comment: Ok never mind, that was silly - obviously I won't be using `pushNavigationController` if I'm not using a navigation controller haha. I changed it to `present(photoDetailController, animated: true, completion: nil)` and it seems to be working now. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: @KingTim Welcome mate :)